# fluentd subsitute ruby function in variable

Tags: ruby, fluentd

I have the following filter in fluentd conf :

```
<filter syslog.local7**>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    raw_message ${record.sub ',', ''}
  </record>
</filter>
```

I'd like to use the ruby variable, `record` and remove commas, at the same time.
How would you do it ? My example is not working. But usage of `${record}` does work

thanks

Comment: it says  `error_class=NoMethodError error="undefined method `gsub' for #<Hash:0x0000000003706d10>"`

Comment: How does your log look like? Please add that in your question.

Comment: In addition, `record` is a Ruby Hash. You need to iterate over its key-value pairs to do some processing. Here's an example of removing commas in the values: `${record.each { |k,v| puts k, v.sub(',', '') } }`. It will print hash keys and values (without commas) on STDOUT. But, I suspect that you want to convert the `record` itself to a string.

Comment: Yes I'd like to convert Record itself to a string and remove comma in string. do you have an idea please ?

Comment: Could you share your sample log?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working like this:

`raw_message2 ${record.to_s.gsub(',', '-')}`

thanks